# New module for ASpnetboilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have added a new module under Areas folder and called it Order. I've created a controller and then index view. What are other items/folders into this area to get the same look as Mpa area?

Comment: sorry your question is too wide to have an answer.

Comment: I want to add a new module in ASPNetBoilerplate. Should I create new project or just add an Area under Areas folder?

Answer (score 0):

An assembly is considered as a module. So create a new project. If you created an application with more than one assembly, it's suggested to create a module definition for each assembly.

A module is defined with a class that is derived from **AbpModule**

```
[DependsOn(typeof(MyBlogCoreModule))]
public class MyBlogApplicationModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a sample project where I can download?

Comment: please read the module system for further information https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Module-System